# SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory only works alternately on SpringAndroid

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate

I am using SpringAndroid M4.

I have the following fragment of code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(myHeader());
final String url = "my_url";
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
    restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Believe it or not it works alternately (first time yes, then no, then yes, then no, and so on..)

This is the stack trace of the error (error is thrown on restTemplate.exchange method) when it doesn't work:

```
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [-1]
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722):     at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:380)
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722):     at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:48)
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722):     at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:45)
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:463)
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:425)
08-18 17:55:09.919: ERROR/(7722):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:401)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen only when testing on the emulator?
I have exactly the same problem, but it only occurs when i use the emulator. 
Everything works fine on a real device.

Comment: nope, problem on the device as well. every second request works fine. therefore I just set up a trick to sort out the problem. Catching the exception and then repeat the request in the catch code... it was the easiest thing, very dirty, but it works. mysteries...

Comment: Very strange indeed. I have just noticed the error showing up on a real device as well. Not every 2nd request though. I think I'll have to catch it and repeat the request like you are doing now.

Comment: Have you tried using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory instead? This seems to resolve the problem.
Have you seen this thread already? http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124053-IllegalArgumentException-No-matching-constant-for-1-after-upgrading-from-M4-to-RC

Comment: No did not try, thanks for the link. Let's see also what the community says after reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in `SimpleClientHttpResponse`. In my case it didn't seem to have any implications, although possibly the HTTP return code is incorrect.

By replacing it with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, the problem appears to have disappeared.